# How to tell if GCM token is valid, without sending a notification?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to tell when a GCM token is no longer valid, without actually attempting to send a notification and receive an error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the dry run feature provided by the google.

When sending request for a notification from your web server to GCM servers you can add **dry_run** key to be **true**

This parameter allows developers to test a request without actually sending a message.  The default value is false, and it must be a JSON boolean.

If the Notification key is invalid it would give the corresponding http response of the request

Comment: just for the record: this way you may check the token's validity. this does not mean the notification is actually sent to any device. i tried it with a token of a three years old version of our app and it didn't complain, but this notification will never be delivered to a device ...

Comment: is there any limit for dry run tests??

Comment: @masSdev i dont think so

Comment: will the order of results in  http response returned by gcm is same as what we sent?? i mean reg token order and results are same?? Does google guarentee that?

Comment: @masSdev it is not guarenteed

Comment: @lakshay but in the documents it is written like the order of message recieved in the device is not guaranteed,not the http response,do you have any documents or link regarding this?