# How to know which GCM registration ids are still in use?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We provide a service which has collected a lot of GCM registration ids over the last couple of years. We are wondering how many of these are still being used. We send millions of push notifications but we don't know which actually arrives on a device.

I followed the advice of some answers here on StackOverflow to check the validity of registration ids/push tokens [using a dry_run flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002758/how-to-tell-if-gcm-token-is-valid-without-sending-a-notification).

That works fine to sort out tokens that are not valid (like *asdf*). But I also checked some ids of mine, all of them were valid. Even my oldest token (> 3 years old) of a device that is not in use anymore for 2 years now. Sending notifications to this token will never arrive on a device for sure.

Any idea on how we can check if a token/registration id still delivers notifications?

Thanks!

Comment: Just want to confirm, have you actually tested each token/registration ids in your device (by actually sending messages) if you can still receive notifications?

Comment: Yes I could for the latest ones, after half a year tokens were not working any more.

Answer (score 0):

After some days I came across the FCM statistics panel in the google's developer console. It shows how many messages are sent and how many could be delivered to devices. This does not allow me to judge on individual tokens, but it gets me a general picture.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en